# How do I toggle, (switch, alternate) an element between being visible and hidden using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to make it so that if you click on the "test header" it hides the test content then if you click "test header" it shows it again.

http://jsfiddle.net/ahaz86/4asqs/

Currently, my code will hide the test content. What I want to happen is for the test content to toggle between being visible and hidden.

HTML:

```
<div class="content_list_container">
<div class="content_list_title" align="left">test header</div>
<div class="content_list_menu_items">
<ul>
    test
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $(".content_list_title").click(
            function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("selected");  
                $(this).next(".content_list_menu_items").hide();
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Have tried using the .toggle() method and it does not seem to work on my site. Is there a way to do this using the show() and hide() methods even though it is not ideal?

Comment: I'm curious why you switch between using $ and using the full jQuery.

Comment: Please invest at least enough time in your question to indent the code properly.

Comment: jQuery(this).next(".content_list_menu_items").toggle();

Answer (score 5):

You can `toggle` method instead of `hide`:

```
jQuery(this).next(".content_list_menu_items").toggle();
```

Comment: I have tried this but for some reason it does not actually work on my site. the .hide() works but i am very new to jquery

Comment: Yea, i see it works in there, just not sure why it wouldnt actually work on the site im using it on...

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent'

This shows up with both the toggle and hide method though and the hide method is working :/

Comment: @AlexHazlett okay, you should trace the error, see which line throw this error.